# Is there a way to reflect current state of many-to-many relationship in a form of multiple checkbox fields?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, wtforms

Is there a way to reflect current state of many-to-many relationship on multiple choice field checkboxes?

given working many to many relationship between Song and Tag tables. here is the layout:

```
songtags = db.Table('songtags', 
                    db.Column('song_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('song.id')), 
                    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id')))

class Song(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255), index=True)
    ...
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=songtags, backref='songs', lazy='dynamic')
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Song {}>'.format(self.title)

class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Tag {}>'.format(self.name)
```

In shell assigning tags to song works. and are shown as list of strings on the page using `tagged_list = ([tag.name for tag in song.tags])` and `{% for t in tagged_list %}`.

I have tried next:

```
        elif tags_form.validate_on_submit():
            ...
            for t in selected_tags:
                song.tags.append(t)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('.view_song', id=song.id, key=key))
        elif request.method == 'GET':
            tags_form.name.data = Tag.query.filter(Tag.songs.any(song.id==id)).all()
```

Maybe its because of `Tag.query.filter(Tag.songs.any(song.id==id)).all()` I am calling for a assigned list of tags to particular song only. and this does not change the state of checkboxes on the website.

Could someone please help me to grasp how can I reflect current state of tags of particular song?

__ UPDATE __

I found my issue:
for some reason wtforms passes 'name-#' when I call for `{{ name.id }}`. I suspect that it's the main reason for my issue.

for now decided to manually insert checked property to input using jinja syntax (although I'd prefer to avoid this at any cost):

```
{% set is_checked = name.id in song.tags %}
    {% set a = name.id[5:] %}
    {% set aa = a|int + 1|int %}
    {{ tag_states[aa|int] }}
    {{ name(class_="form-check-input", checked=tag_states[aa|int]) }}
    {{ name.label(class_="form-check-label") }}
```

and sending tag_states dict like so:

```
for tag in tags:
    tag_states[tag.id] = tag in song.tags
```

currently `form=Tagsform(obj=myobj)` alongside widgets do not properly work, since wtforms passes `id's` of SelectMultipleField as string `name-#`.

spent so much time solving this issue. Hope for any help?

Answer (score 0):

Tried to go other way:
in my GET method:

```
form.key.data = song.key
for tag in tags:
    tag_states[tag.id] = tag in song.tags
```

tag_states gives me {1:True, 2: False ...}

so with if statement `{% if tag_states[tag.id] %}checked{% endif %}` in input tag I had succeeded in reflecting active tags.

though not sure if its a proper solution to my issue. my route class is becoming too complicated. And I would definitely like any opinion on this matter

-UPDATE-

Will keep it as last resort. since its still brute forcing, currently searching for other solutions.

have tried to pass a list of selected tags in form=TagsForm(obj=" "). no luck.